# Replace anchor tag with href in parenthesis

Tags: php, html

I want to replace a html anchor tag with the href part only in plain text.

So,

```
$input = "Please go to <a href='http://www.google.com' style='color:red'>Google</a> or <a href='http://www.yahoo.com' style='color:red'>Yahoo</a> and search.";

echo fixlinks($input);

// "Please go to Google (http://www.google.com) or Yahoo (http://www.yahoo.com) and search."
```

Update: I was able to do it using a regex, but it would also need to work for many urls in the input string

Update: Ending up doing this, a variation of Elmo's answer below:

```
preg_replace("/<a.+href=['|\"]([^\"\']*)['|\"].*>(.+)<\/a>/i",'\2 (\1)',$html)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex in PHP:

```
$input_string = "Please go to <a href='http://www.google.com' style='color:red'>Google</a> and search.";
$pattern = "/<a[\w\s\.]*href='([\w:\-\/\.]*)'[\w\s\.\=':>]+<\/a>/";
$replacement = '(\1)';
$output_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input_string);
```

This regular expression matches the entire `a` tag with it's contents and standalone `href` value. Then simple `preg_replace` function replaces matched `a` tags with matched `href` values.

Comment: @danielb I've updated the answer and now it supports multiple anchors.

Comment: Thanks doesn't seem to work though. It returns "Please go to () and search"

Comment: But it was tested - you had to misspell something http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4LC

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry - the error was in the third line - double quotes caused treating `\` as escape character. Single quotes should be used here.

Comment: I ended up using this, a variation of what you wrote. What do you think?

preg_replace("/<a.+href=['|\"]([^\"\']*)['|\"].*>(.+)<\/a>/i",'\2 (\1)',$html)

Answer (score 0):

You can either rewrite all the HTML to be:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> (http://www.google.com)
```

or you can use javascript to automatically do that all the `<a>` tags in your page:

```
var theLinks=document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var x=0; x<theLinks.length; x++){
  theLinks[x].outerHTML+=" ("+theLinks[x].href+")";
}
```

I'm not actually entirely sure that travestial usage of `outerHTML` will work, but you could easily append that to the `innerHTML` to also hyper-link-ify the URL text, and that will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general version (this one is shorter and more reliable):

`preg_replace('/<a.*href=["\']([^"\']*)["\'].*>(.*)<\/a>/U', '\2 (\1)', $input);`

Why is it better?

- It handles both types of quotation marks `["\']`
- It uses `([^"\']*)` (anything that's not a quote) to capture the URL, so it can handle any href you supply.
- It uses `(.*)` to capture the link text, so it can handle pretty much any link text you supply.
- Note that it needs the `U` modifier to make those two captures non-greedy.

Here it is in action: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/t9s#tab-preg-replace